# How does the East Coast Discovery Pass work in Australia?

Tags: trains, australia

I've been reading about the East Coast Discovery Pass for trains in Australia. It seems that it's a pass for 6 months with the only restriction that you pay for travel in one direction from city A city to city B.

Is it possible to make as many stops as I want? For instance, if I buy a Sydney to Cairns pass, may I make a route like this?

```
Sydney -> Gloucester (2 days here)
Gloucester -> Coffs Harbour (3 days here)
Coffs Harbour -> Brisbane (5 days here)
Brisbane -> .....
```

Comment: No, I want to travel Sydney to Cairns, this is an example :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are:

(a) a Discovery Pass, which allows unlimited train travel within 'New South Wales' (including between Sydney, Brisbane, Melbourne and Canberra) – but not including Cairns.

(b) a Queensland Explorer Pass, which  allows unlimited travel on most Queensland rail services.

(c) a Queensland Coastal Pass, which allows one-way travel between Brisbane and Cairns (or vice versa), with an unlimited number of stops en route (but only in one or other direction).

So with passes, from Sydney to Cairns you would need (a) and (c). However if not making various breaks in the journey, a 'regular' train ticket or tickets might cost less.

Comment: Yes, I know about these passes you mention, but I found some info about another pass, the East Coast Discovery Pass here: http://www.train-ticket.net/austral/ecoast.htm This allows to travel between two given points, but there is a lack of information and I can't find reliable sources that answers my question: does this pass allows unlimited stops? It seems that that's the way it works, but I'd like to double check (and also find a trustable website that sells it, but that's another question)...

Comment: So, your opinion is that the info in this website is outdated? Probably you are right. In my opinion, this website doesn't seem too trustable and that's why I've asked about this topic .